# CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync is slower than GetContainer?

Tags: azure, api, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am using Azure cosmosDB SDK v3.As you know the SDK supports **CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync** which creates a container if there is no container matching provided container id. This is convenient.
But it pings Cosmos DB to know container exists or not whereas **GetContainer** doesn't as **GetContainer** assumes container exists. So **CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync** would need one more round trip to Cosmos DB for most of operations if my understanding is correct.

So my questions is would it better to avoid using **CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync** as much as possible in terms of API perspective? Api can have better latency and save bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different is explained in the Intellisense, `GetContainer` just returns a proxy object, one that simply gives you the ability to execute operations within that container, it performs no network requests. If, for example, you try to read an Item (ReadItemAsync) on that proxy and the container does not exist (which also makes the item non-existent) you will get a 404 response.

`CreateContainerIfNotExists` is also not recommended for hot path operations as it involves a metadata or management plane operation:

> Retrieve the names of your databases and containers from configuration or cache them on start. Calls like ReadDatabaseAsync or ReadDocumentCollectionAsync and CreateDatabaseQuery or CreateDocumentCollectionQuery will result in metadata calls to the service, which consume from the system-reserved RU limit. CreateIfNotExist should also only be used once for setting up the database. Overall, these operations should be performed infrequently.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/best-practice-dotnet for more details

Bottomline: Unless you expect the container to be deleted due to some logical pathway in your application, `GetContainer` is the right way, it gives you a proxy object that you can use to execute Item operations without any network requests.